YouTube videos don't work in Flutter Desktop
I attempted several packages for playing YouTube videos in my Flutter desktop app, including web view and HTML packages, but none worked. I need a reliable solution to embed YouTube content.
help if you work with desktop flutter apps.

try with youtube_player_flutter

Add the youtube_player_flutter package to your pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2

try this code :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:youtube_player_flutter/youtube_player_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: YouTubePlayerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class YouTubePlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YouTubePlayerScreenState createState() => _YouTubePlayerScreenState();
}

class _YouTubePlayerScreenState extends State<YouTubePlayerScreen> {
  late YoutubePlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = YoutubePlayerController(
      initialVideoId: 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', // Replace with your video ID
      flags: YoutubePlayerFlags(
        autoPlay: true,
        mute: false,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('YouTube Player'),
      ),
      body: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,
        progressIndicatorColor: Colors.amber,
        onReady: () {
          print('Player is ready.');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Try this

thank you Anu but it doesn't work.
